# Audio - android

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to play an audio in android app but in the code there is error in `AssetFileDescriptor asset1` and the line under it. This is the code:

```
MediaPlayer mp; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        play();
}

 public void play() {

            String file = "audio.mp3";
            AssetFileDescriptor asset1 = getAssets().openFd(file);
            mp.setDataSource(asset1.getFileDescriptor(), asset1.getStartOffset(), asset1.getLength());
            asset1.close();

            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
    }
```

Can u help me to find a solution.

Comment: Where you are initializing the **MediaPlayer** ??

Comment: You declare the variable 'mp' but never set it to an instance of an object. In onCreate() add: mp = new MediaPlayer(); You'll also need a try/catch as indicated by InnocentKiller.

Comment: you all right , I initialize mp now inside on create .

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
public void play() {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("audio.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this solution and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: it try it now but the audio does not play when i run the app

Comment: @user3347841, can you check it now.